# What is the difference between pandas' df.take() and df.iloc[]?

Tags: pandas, indexing

To me, it seems `df.take()` has the same functionality as the more common `df.iloc[]`. I've checked the documentation but couldn't find a difference. Are there cases where `take()` is preferable to `iloc[]`?

Comment: df.take return dataframes with values  along an axis for specific indices; iloc can return dataframes with indices for both rows and columns. since df.take is restricted in its functionality, usually it is faster. Read [take methods](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/advanced.html#take-methods) for more

Comment: thank you, that makes sense.

Comment: @sammywemmy are you sure that .take is usually faster? Since it always copies the data I would assume it's usually slower. Do you have a reference for that?

Comment: I think a lot of operations in Pandas require copying; but take has a narrower reference sort of. Here is the [reference](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/advanced.html#take-methods) in the pandas docs

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are some pretty important differences:

1. .iloc is of type <class 'pandas.core.indexing._iLocIndexer'>, whereas .take is a method
2. *Most important* .iloc can index into rows AND columns at the same time. .take can only select from one or the other.
3. .take always returns a DataFrame with the same number of levels in both axes. In contrast, .iloc can easily return fewer levels, to the point of totally returning a Series instead of a DataFrame, i.e. df.iloc[3, :] returns a Series with the columns as the index, but df.take([3]) returns a DataFrame with only one row.
4. Also pretty important, .take always returns a copy. This means that you can also use .iloc for assignment, but this is not the case for .take.

Answer (score 0):

Case:
I received the following error message and finally figured out that it was hanging up on the .iloc.

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Since the iloc returned a list which is mutable, the code wouldn't proceed with the summation. A simple change from .iloc to .take fixed the problem.

```
#returns list
df3['sum_total']= df3.iloc[:,-30].sum(axis=[1])
#returns tuple and worked
df3['sum_total']= df3.take([-30], axis=1).sum(axis=1)
```